# Javascript list like data structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It seems, if I'm not wrong, that because of the way Javascript handles Objects it is unpractical or inefficient to implement linked lists.

I would need a data structure in which I could easily do 2 operations(apart from indexing), appending at the end and removing (popping) an object at a given index.

Is using an `Array` and "recreating" it for each remove operation the optimal solution? I would think not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the [JS Array](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) is exactly what you're looking for.
You should be able to use the push and pop functions for the stack-like data structure and splice for the rest of it.

Comment: I am stunned, and I got totally misinformed... I'll have to check next time I ask someone if he's good in JavaScript... And thanks, `splice` was what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually `Array` supports `push` and `pop` operations: [JavaScript Array Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to recreate the Javascript array for each removal. Javascript Arrays have `push()` and `pop()` methods to add and remove elements:

[JavaScript Array Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

Comment: As well as shift and unshift.  Note the footer on the listed page that provides "try it now" versions of all the methods.